# How do I make a button span across 2 columns?

Tags: css, reactjs, styles

I'm working on a calculator app, and there are very specific things that I want for it. I want the colors of the buttons to vary and I want the "0" button to span across the two front columns so that the buttons beside it will be the same size as the rest. I think that just looks better. I have tried many things and none of them worked. I created my own button component and here is all the code that I think is necessary to show:
[image]

```
This is my App.js file
```

```
return (
    <div className='App'>
        <div className='calculator'>
            <ResultBar />
            <div className='row'>
                <Button color="#625C5D" symbol="Clear" />
                <Button color="#625C5D" symbol="+/-" />
                <Button color="#625C5D" symbol="%" />
                <Button color="#B04929" symbol="/" />
            </div>
            <div className='row'>
                <Button symbol="7" />
                <Button symbol="8" />
                <Button symbol="9" />
                <Button color="#B04929" symbol="x" />
            </div>
            <div className='row'>
                <Button symbol="4" />
                <Button symbol="5" />
                <Button symbol="6" />
                <Button color="#B04929" symbol="-" />
            </div>
            <div className='row'>
                <Button symbol="1" />
                <Button symbol="2" />
                <Button symbol="3" />
                <Button color="#B04929" symbol="+" />
            </div>
            <div className='row'>
                <Button style={{columnSpan: 2}} symbol="0"/>
                <Button symbol="." />
                <Button color="#B04929" symbol="=" />
            </div>
            {/* <div className='display'>
                {result ? <span>({result})</span> : '0'}&nbsp;
            </div> */}
            {/* <div className='keyboard'>
            </div> */}
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

```
This is my button component
```

```
import "./Button.css";

const Button = ({ symbol, color }) => {
    return (
        <div style={{ backgroundColor: color }} className="button-styles">
            {symbol}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Button;

And here's the css for the button
```

```
.button-styles {
    height: 4em;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgb(229, 143, 82);
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    flex: 1;
    margin: 4px;
    border-radius: 16px;
}
```

At first I tried making a classname called button-span-two and added the line
grid-column: span 2;
Then I tried adding a property like symbol and color in the button component to add to the styles that would represent the number of columns to span. I tried using both gridColumn and columnSpan for this. Then I tried making a separate component with its own css file called ButtonSpan that would basically be the same as my button component but with a grid-column property set to 1/3. None of these worked. The calculator stayed the same with each try.

Comment: You may want to try `grid-column: span 2 / span 2`.

Comment: provide code in code sandbox, so someone can check it. otherwise provide `CSS` of classes `calculator` and `row`.

Comment: Have you looked into having the whole thing as one grid, 12 columns wide, rather than separate out the rows in the HTML?,